# Customize User-Facing Pages for Parse Emails

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, html-email

How can I customize the look and feel of my registration email? In my Parse dashboard, it asks me to upload templates to my "server". I don't have a server for my app. It's fairly basic and depends solely on Parse for my back-end.

Can I just provide a link from, say, a GoDaddy hosting account to the specified HTML template pages provided?

**Customize User-Facing Pages**

```
 These are the pages your users visit when resetting their password or
 verifying their email addresses. You can customize the look and feel of
 these pages by uploading a modified copy to your server and telling us
 their locations.
```

**Hide Parse.com URLs**

```
By uploading this file to your server and entering its address below,
you can hide parse.com from your users. This page is an iframe for Parse
that lets your domain be the front-end to our back-end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this was really easy.

Just download the provided template files from your Parse.com Dashboard under Settings > Email, then upload them to your server (web host, i.e. GoDaddy).

Where it says /app/password_reset_success.html, etc., replace that entire line with a link to that same file on your server.